# How i can restrict an sftp user for rename and append any uploaded file or directory

Tags: permissions, sftp

How i can restrict an sftp user from renaming or appending any uploaded file or directory?

Comment: Could you state which SFTP (SSH) server you are using.  Is this OpenSSH server?

Answer (score 1):

Chown filename to another/higher user, possible root

Comment: I was about to give the same answer. A bit longer: After upload of files use an automated process that does what Olaf suggests.